# Redirect User after succesful authenication - Flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, authentication

I am trying to redirect the user to the app home screen after a succesful authentication. In my code I tried to handle the user flow through the future class but I have not been succesful.

**User repository**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_session/flutter_session.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//Authenication: confirms if password and mail matches with server.
Future<UserInfo> authenticate(String email, String password) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('api url'),       //Makes the post request
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{                                    //Input values from the form given to the json of the request.
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    })
  );

  UserInfo id = UserInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));             //Call the function that creates the class with the output of the json
                          
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return UserInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } 
  else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    await FlutterSession().set('id', id);                                 //Saves the id to the session variables
  }
  else {
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
}

class UserInfo {
    
  final int id;

  UserInfo({this.id});

  factory UserInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {                  //Parses through the response´s json and creates a class with that value
    return UserInfo(
      id: json['id_usuario'] as int,
    );
  }
}
```

In here I make a http post request and create a class that contains some of the json instances in return. I also store the instance id into the flutter_session plugin for later queries like user name.

**Login page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:treelife_flutter/user/repository/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:treelife_flutter/user/ui/screens/sign_in_screen.dart';
import 'package:treelife_flutter/user/ui/widgets/background.dart';
import 'package:treelife_flutter/widgets/button_back.dart';
import 'package:treelife_flutter/widgets/button_green.dart';
import 'package:treelife_flutter/widgets/text_input.dart';

import '../../../tree_life_cupertino.dart';


class LogInScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LogInScreenState createState() => _LogInScreenState();
}

class _LogInScreenState extends State<LogInScreen> {

  final _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _mailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  Future<UserInfo> _futureUserInfo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,                                 // Avoid overfloww when keyboard shows
        body: Stack(     
          children: [
            Background(
              height: null,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        ButtonBack(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context, 
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInScreen() )
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(                                                 // Título    
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Ingresa",
                            style:  Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40, top: 40),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/icons/logo_treelife.png'),
                  ),
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _loginFormKey,
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(                                        
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 30),
                            child: TextInput(
                              controller: _mailController,
                              hint: 'Email',
                              suffixIcon:'assets/icons/at.png'
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(                                         //  Primer campo registro: contraseña
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 30),
                            child: TextInput(
                              controller: _passwordController,
                              hint: 'Contraseña',
                              suffixIcon:'assets/icons/password.png'
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ButtonGreen(                                             // Botón Registro
                          marginTop: 30,
                          marginLeft: 30,
                          marginRight: 30,
                          marginBottom: 30,
                          text: "¡Plantemos árboles!",
                          fontColor: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _futureUserInfo = authenticate(_mailController.text, _passwordController.text);
                            });
                          },
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 50,
                          boxColor: Color(0xFFD2E1BD),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/sign_in/login_illustration.png'),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  FutureBuilder<UserInfo> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<UserInfo>(
      future: _futureUserInfo,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Navigator.push(
            context, 
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TreelifeCupertino()));
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In here I followed the flutter *send data to the internet* documentation where I try to apply come logic through the buildfuture function but instead I added the `navigate.of(context)` to redirect if the authentication was succesful.

Comment: When the user is succesfully authenticated, the server should send a response back, can you check if the response code is 200 or the one you expect, and then, redirect to the screen you want, if the response is not the one you expect, you can show a dialog telling the user to input the correct answer or something

Comment: So basically when the `ButtonGreen` is pressed, it should authenticate the user and redirect to home screen right? Then I don't see any code in `onPressed` of `ButtonGreen` that executes `Navigator`'s `push()` method. But it just updates `_futureUserInfo`.

Note that `buildFutureBuilder()` method has never been executed anywhere.